# Faster method of Grouping Times

Tags: java

I receive a json object filled with data and one of the tasks with this data is to group the times together.

For example, if `GAME_TIME` is 12:15 PM it should be under the 12 PM header.

I came up with a solution but its a monstrosity and will be difficult to debug, there has to be a better way to do this.

```
    DbDate = DateFormatter.parse(json_data.getString("GAME_TIME"));

if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("12:00 AM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("1:00 AM") ) < 0)  {
    Users12AM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("1:00 AM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("2:00 AM"))  < 0) {
    Users1AM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("2:00 AM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("3:00 AM"))  < 0) {
    Users2AM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("3:00 AM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("4:00 AM"))  < 0) {
    Users3AM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("4:00 AM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("5:00 AM"))  < 0) {
    Users4AM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("5:00 AM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("6:00 AM"))  < 0) {
    Users5AM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("6:00 AM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("7:00 AM"))  < 0) {
    Users6AM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("7:00 AM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("8:00 AM"))  < 0) {
    Users7AM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("8:00 AM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("9:00 AM"))  < 0) {
    Users8AM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("9:00 AM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("10:00 AM"))  < 0) {
    Users9AM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("10:00 AM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("11:00 AM"))  < 0) {
    Users10AM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("11:00 PM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("12:00 PM"))  < 0) {
    Users11AM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("12:00 PM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("1:00 PM"))  < 0) {
    Users12PM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("1:00 PM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("2:00 PM"))  < 0) {
    Users1PM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("2:00 PM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("3:00 PM"))  < 0) {
    Users2PM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("3:00 PM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("4:00 PM"))  < 0) {
    Users3PM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("4:00 PM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("5:00 PM"))  < 0) {
    Users4PM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("5:00 PM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("6:00 PM"))  < 0) {
    Users5PM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("6:00 PM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("7:00 PM"))  < 0) {
    Users6PM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("7:00 PM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("8:00 PM"))  < 0) {
    Users7PM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("8:00 PM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("9:00 PM"))  < 0) {
    Users8PM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("9:00 PM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("10:00 PM"))  < 0) {
    Users9PM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("10:00 PM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("11:00 PM"))  < 0) {
    Users10PM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
} else if (DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("11:00 PM")) == 0 || DbDate.compareTo(DateFormatter.parse("12:00 PM"))  < 0) {
    Users11PM.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
}
```

Comment: Ever hear of a `Map` ? `Map<Integer, List<String>>`

Comment: just commenting the code itself not the question: please,please use lower case variable names for objects!! if any developer reads Users2PM.add(), they think about static methods, which I hope is not the case here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store everything in a `HashMap<Date,String>`. `Date` is the key, identifying the "group", and the `String` is your `ingame_name`.
You could first fill the `HashMap` with all empty groups, and then iterate over them.

Comment: I decided to use this solution because I already have code to iterate over a map. Though all of these suggestions are great ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you can extract the hour from your `DbDate` object, whatever that is. Convert it to 24hr time. If you can't a `Calendar` certainly can do this for you.

Extract the hour as 0 - 23, use that as a key for `Map`, store a list of `String`s in the `Map`. Done.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
...

// `hour` here represents the 24hr value described above
List<String> list = myMap.get(hour);
if (null == list) 
{
    // There's no List for this hour - create and insert it.
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    myMap.put(hour, list);
}
list.add(json_data.getString("IN_GAME_NAME"));
```

If you'd like to skip the `null` check bit and be guaranteed there's a `List` for every hour, pre-populate the `Map` with a loop, creating and inserting the `List<String>` for each hour 0 - 23.

Answer (score 0):

There is. Use a database. This is exactly what in-memory SQLite databases are meant for. Simply create an `SQLiteOpenHelper` object, passing `null` as the `name` and you will get an in-memory, this-process-only SQL database.

Then, just dump all the data into a table and run something akin to `SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY time(date_field) ASC`. See [Date & Time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for more info.

You can of course do a lot more processing on the SQLite side so that you express it in a language meant for data processing.

Alternatively, you can of course create a `Comparator` and use `Collections.sort()` to achieve a similar effect.